# Relative reference is not working when I fill down or use format painter

Tags: excel, reference, formatting

I am using Microsoft Excel conditional formating and the relative reference is not working when I fill down or use format painter. However, it does work when I copy one cell and "paste special" "formats" to the one below.

Column G has dates which I want to compare to be less than column D plus 14 days. If column G is greater than 14 days from column D, I want it to be red.
It will not work if I select the entire column and paste because it ends up keeping the reference to D2.

It will not work if I select all the rows in column G, then type the formatting because it ends up only references D2 in each row of G.

Here is what I have in the Conditional Formating Rules Manager

```
Rule: Cell Value >D2 + 14  
Format: Red  
Applies to: =$G$2
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you talking about Excel or something else?

Comment: any ideas Nanhydrin?

Comment: None. I was just trying to clarify your question so it would get in front of someone who might thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rule: Cell Value >D2 + 14  
Format: Red  
Applies to: =$G$2
```

And copy down. Take out the '$'

Comment: Can someone explain why it works to copy and paste the format of one cell but then will not work when I select multiple rows and paste formats on them all at the same time? ( I took all $ out)